# Programmatically access Repeater using child RepeaterItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a bunch of repeaters which require similar handling. But the handler requires access, not only to the RepeaterItem which is a subject of the command, but also its containing Repeater.

```
protected void SpecificRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GenericHandler(e);
}

private void GenericHandler(RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) 
{
    RepeaterItem row = e.Item;
    // Do things with the item.

    Repeater table = e.<???>;
    // Do things with the repeater.
}
```

Basically I'm asking what goes in `<???>`. How can I get the repeater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ItemCommand, the source is the Repeater itself, not the button. So cast the source back to a Repeater.

```
protected void SpecificRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Repeater repeater = source as Repeater;
    GenericHandler(e, repeater);
}

private void GenericHandler(RepeaterCommandEventArgs e, Repeater repeater)
{
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Out of curiosity, could the signature of the first method be `Repeater source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e`? That seems more readable/maintainable, and probably would have saved me the trouble of a SE post.

Comment: No it cannot: `No overload for 'SpecificRepeater_ItemCommand' matches delegate 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventHandler'`